# Erro C2664: Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CustomImport::ICustomImportPtr' to '__missing_type__ *'

Tags: visual-c++

I'm migrating a project from vs 6.0 to vs 2008, I get the following error,

```
error C2664: 'Policy::IBusinessImport::SetCustomImport' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CustomImport::ICustomImportPtr' to '__missing_type__ *'
```

Code Used:

```
m_spBusinessImport->SetCustomImport(m_spCustomImport); //C2664
```

Definition of `m_spCustomImport`:

```
CustomImport::ICustomImportPtr m_spCustomImport;
```

Definition of `m_spBusinessImport`:

```
Policy::IBusinessImportPtr m_spBusinessImport;
```

Definition of SetCustomImport:

```
HRESULT SetCustomImport (
    __missing_type__ * customImport );
```

I'm very new to VC++, Any help to fix this error is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Ankush.